# use contour integration to find $\int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{1}{\cos x - 2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate using contour integration:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{1}{\cos x - 2}dx$$

The problem is $\cos x \neq 2$, its range is $[-1,1]$, unless the unit circle is expanded by a factor of $2$. How do I apply Cauchy's Formula. Do I reparmeterize it? Using $\gamma(t)=e^{i t}$? Then I would get

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\cos(e^{it})-2} \cdot ie^{it}dt$$

Then I can make A $u-$substitution?

Comment: $\cos x = \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$ simplify and make the substitution $z = e^{ix}$ you will get an integral around the contour $|z| = 1$ with a pole inside the contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z=e^{it}$. Then $dt= \frac{dz}{iz}$ and we know that
$$\cos t = \frac{1}{2}\left(z+ z^{-1}\right).$$
So for a contour $C$ given by $\left\{ z=e^{it} , 0\le t \le 2\pi \right\}$
there holds
$$I = \int_C \frac{\frac{dz}{iz}}{ \frac{1}{2}\left(z+ z^{-1}\right)-2} = -2i \int_C \frac{dz}{z^2-4z+1}.$$
To evaluate this integral note that the integrand is analytic except at the zeros of the denominator i.e. $2\pm\sqrt{3}$.
Since only $2-\sqrt{3}$ is inside $C$, you just need to apply the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to obtain
\begin{equation}
I = -2i(2\pi i)\cdot \text{res}_{z=2-\sqrt{3}}\,\frac{1}{z^2-4z+1}=-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}.
\end{equation}
You can confirm this in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E%7B2pi%7D1%2F%28cos%28x%29-2%29dx).

I hope this helps.